# How to transpose dynamic matrix dataset in EXCEL or SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, transpose, vba

I have the following issue that I can't find the best solution for.

I need to align hours per date per ID from a sheet with these parameters. I tried transposing in excel but I just came with a summier result that wouldn't give the rows per ID and date.

HOURS WORKSHEET

YEAR = 2015

```
ID | MON | TUES | WED | THU | FRI | SAT | SUN | WEEKNR

15 |  6  |  8   |  9  |  -  |  -  |  -  |  -  |  14
16 |  -  |  -   |  2  |  -  |  3  |  -  |  -  |  14
17 |  -  |  3   |  5  |  -  |  -  |  5  |  -  |  14
18 |  9  |  -   |  -  |  3  |  -  |  -  |  -  |  14
```

I'd like to have the ID transposed on the date with the values(hours) like this

```
ID | DATE      | HOURS

15 | 30-3-2015 |  6
15 | 31-3-2015 |  8
15 |  1-4-2015 |  9
16 |  1-4-2015 |  2
16 |  3-4-2015 |  3
17 | 31-3-2015 |  3
17 |  1-4-2015 |  5
17 |  4-4-2015 |  5
18 | 30-3-2015 |  9
18 |  2-4-2015 |  3
```

Any suggestion/solution is much appreciated. SQL or Excel formula(VBA)

Answer (score 0):

This would be easy in sql-server (using a table function). In MySQL however, simplest way i can think of is this:

```
select id, date (use date_ADD() to deduce this), mon as hours from table
union all
select id, date (use date_ADD() to deduce this), tues as hours from table
union all
select id, date (use date_ADD() to deduce this), wed as hours from table
union all
select id, date (use date_ADD() to deduce this), thu as hours from table
union all
select id, date (use date_ADD() to deduce this), fri as hours from table
union all
select id, date (use date_ADD() to deduce this), sat as hours from table
union all
select id, date (use date_ADD() to deduce this), sun as hours from table
```

And then sort as needed.

EDIT: if you need help with the date, tell us.

Comment: Thank you very much Mihai. I will look into it and let you know.